# Why is this random act of kindness considered offensive flirting?

Tags: flirting, act-of-kindness

In [Offering to share my umbrella without sounding creepy](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/18643/) op, assumed to be a man, shares an umbrella with a woman because it's raining a lot. For some reason good portion of the response to this question revolves around flirting.

Given the situation, I don't understand why this is considered flirting at all. Furthermore, the top answer for this question mentions giving the woman the umbrella when she wants to part ways so she won't get wet. I'll be honest. This move is pure class from my point of view. It's just something you do if you're not going to walk another couple of miles in the rain. The issue is that in the last sentence of this paragraph the answerer mentions a date being a possible result of this action.

What followed this was a bunch of push back from who I can only assume to be women about how this was bad. None of the people who had a problem with this actually engaged with the act of giving someone else an umbrella. All of the comments were about the inclusion of a possibility of a date being a massive problem. Even the mod who deleted said string of comments asked for it to be removed.

Why is the suggestion of a date being a possible outcome of an interaction so offensive?

There are a few other answers to this question which also state that op seems to have been flirting and such kindness would have made the answerers uncomfortable. I just don't get it.

I tried to hash this out in the comments, but this doesn't seem appropriate to discuss there for whatever reason.

tl:dr;

Why is the suggestion of a date being a possible outcome of an interaction so offensive?

Comment: "Is this offensive?" Is a opinion based question, and given that this question focuses on another question on the site it may be better to take this to [meta].

Comment: This might be OK as a meta question.

Comment: @apaul "Is this offensive?" is not my question. My question is about why there's a problem with the suggestion that a date might be an outcome. There's a big difference between being unsure something is offensive and wanting to understand why any sees it as a problem.

Comment: @apaul Take my question off hold someone else just answered it, in the comments of schoe001's answer based off of specific experience or expertise. Your premise for putting my question on hold is inaccurate.

Comment: I don't have the ability to single handedly take your question off-hold just as I didn't have the ability to single handedly put it on-hold. 5 users will have to vote to reopen.

Comment: @apaul how do you vote to reopen?

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions If you need further information please feel free to ask a question on [meta].

Comment: @Steve - People who put more into the site are able to get more out of it. And people with a high reputation are trusted more than those with a low reputation. I know, it is frustrating at times, but it is pretty fair and balanced! For what it is worth I think your question here focuses too much on the other question for it to be a question in its own right. Currently it looks a better fit for Meta. You may be able to edit it to make it more suited for here but I can't offer any fool-proof methods. One thing that stands out is you have 2 questions there: why flirty and why is this offensive?

Comment: @Steve: I hope you don't get upset with me for saying this, especially as I think your question is very valid and I understand your frustration (as well as the need to vent out against sb), but I don't think that'll help the situation. Each Stack has its own answer-question sensitivities and even the best system will have unfair flaws. I can only offer some ideas to rephrase: say, how can one explain to a young man what is wrong about the particular situation in question.

Comment: Also, perhaps just mention - link to the other question but then focus on what is the problwm with the last sentence of the top answer.

Comment: @SaraCosta I'll do some thinking. Rewrite incoming.

Comment: @Steve if you think something is offensive, there's flags for that on IPS. If you want to discuss whether or not an answer is offensive (because of e.g. a declined flag) or has no place on the site as it isn't about Interpersonal Skills, that's a question for meta. Generally, 'why do people consider X to be offensive/rude/fun' is a primarily opinion based question, that has no answer to be found in Interpersonal Skills. If anything, it's more a question of anthropology/sociology (for which there is no stackexchange site) or better suited to a forum.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Offering help with ulterior romantic motive is usually fine, provided the intent is clear *and the recipient has the option of turning down said help.* If both conditions are met, I could see the offer to help as a flirtatious gesture, or the start of one.

However, the issue here is that the recipient in question is in a tough spot where it would be harmful to her to turn down OP's help. She was out uncovered in the "menacing rain" after all. So if OP is only helping because of an ulterior motive, it gives the situation a slimy feel by making it seem like OP is taking advantage of someone else's misfortune to get them to let him close when ordinarily they wouldn't have. Would he have helped if the girl were less pretty? If it was a guy instead? Not to mention that now that he's helped will he feel like she owes him something? What if he acts on this?

And this is the basis for the question OP asked. How can he take what might be a flirtatious situation and make it clear that he is just trying for a random act of kindness. This is why, when the top answer mentions "get[ting] a date afterwards," it comes off as a little tone deaf. The whole point after all was to make it seem like that *wasn't* what OP was expecting.

In other words, to quote a comment on this answer, "To tell anyone you 'could' get something out of a kind act is, IMO, taking the 'kindness' out of the act."

Comment: Having written that answer I just want to mention it said the he "might even" ... nowhere it stated that he should expect. It was more of a joke as I had a girlfriend that I started seeing after she returned a chair to me after she borrowed it for a random meetup in her dormroom. Just wanted to say that something unexpected might happen. Because it didn't relate to the question and I never imagined that would cause such a fuss. I removed that line today.

Comment: @Ontamu And that was exactly how i picked it up from your answer. I IMHO liked it and dont understand peoples problems. You can do something nice and expect nothing, but if something eveolves it is still nice, which does not mean that the act of kindness was done BECAUSE of the possibility :)

Comment: @MansNotHot: that is why I think this question is important: it gives the opportunity for the reasons behind the knee-jerk reactions to Ontamu's answer  to be clarified. After all, isn't this site supposed to help people understand (as objectively as possible) why certain actions and words should be avoided in favour of others? For what is worth, I understand Ontamu meant nothing that deserved the volumous response, but the response existed nonetheless.

Comment: And if someone is at a loss to understand the reasons behing the response, then I feel asking a new question is the thing to do. I apologise for having ranted a bit (especially as you have nothing to do with it), but, like Steve, I too feel a bit frustrated this question was closed.

Comment: @Ontamu I guess that was worded poorly. I was thinking more that with that line you were planting the thought in OP's head. How else would OP take that except as a confirmation that there is a possibility for a date and a reason to raise his expectations? I understand that's not how you wrote it, but I'm guessing that's how it was interpreted. I've reworded that part of the answer to be more fair to you though, sorry about the misunderstanding.